# mobile safari or jquery BUG ? On html tag label onclick="" and click() fails

Tags: jquery, html, input, safari, click

I found out, that the following code does work

```
<label onclick="alert('alert')">
    <input id="testinput" type="radio" name="test" autocomplete="off" />
    clicktest
</label>
```

but the following doesn't.

```
<label for="testinput" onclick="alert('alert')">clicktest</label>
<input id="testinput" type="radio" name="test" autocomplete="off" />
```

I am using jquery.3.3.1.min.
To clarify, only the coded click event does not work, while the native interaction with the input does.

The same result, if I try to set click events using

```
$('label').click(function(){... do something ...});
```

For those, who stuck with the same problem, here's my workaround, which obviously only targets the usage for `input[type="radio"]` and acts reading the result of clicking the label, when the radio input changes:

```
$('section.tabbox input[type=radio]').change(function(){
    var el = $(this);
    if (el.is(':checked')) {
        var tbb = el.closest('section.tabbox');
        var index = tbb.find('input[type=radio]').index(el);
//--- do more stuff with index
//--- e.g. $('section.tabbox').find('label:eq('+index+').addClass('clicked')
    }
});
```

But what if the inputs property is already `:checked` but you need the click event on the label ? Simply change it twice :-)

```
$(thisinput).prop('checked',false).prop('checked',true)
```

I found this behavior in mobile safari on iPad mini only, other browsers seem not be affected. Is this a bug, in safari or jquery ?

Comment: The mentioned `change it twice` is only an untested idea, untested because I don't know how to set it :-), as a result of another workaround: mobile safari needs to re-render a `select` element after programatical change, like: `$('select').val(newval).change().css('display', 'none').css('display', 'inline-block')`

Answer (score 0):

Hope that this solution I found will be stable in the future (updates will be posted if necessary).

I found out, that

- desktop Firefox and desktop Safari **don't** fire a click on `input type="radio"` after click on `label`
- desktop Chrome fires **both**, click event of `label` and focus/click on `input`
- mobile Safari fires **only** click event on `input`.

Here is my solution, which plays around with `navigator.userAgent` and accepts click events on input[type=radio] only if user agent detects mobile Safari (improvements welcome). This function collects the `onclick="..."` as well as a `.click(...)` event from the relevant label (by its `for`-attribute) and triggers it programatically.

```
$('input[type=radio]').on('click focus',function(){
    var el = $(this);
    el.blur();
    if (/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i.test(navigator.userAgent) && /AppleWebKit/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {    
        $('label[for='+el.attr('id')+']').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

This seems to be a noteworth workaround.

UPDATE 2017/01/03

Kicked out the `focus` notation, as it doesn't make sense. Now only with `click` notation, now also including the test, if a `label` with a matching `for`-attribute exists. This check seems important to me since two html markup possibilities (see beginning of question above) may appear on the same page:

```
$('input[type=radio]').on('click',function(){
    var el = $(this);
    var label = $('label[for='+el.attr('id')+']');
    if (label.length && /iPhone|iPad|iPod/i.test(navigator.userAgent) && /AppleWebKit/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {    
        label.trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Cheers